# Is it possible from Spring to inject the result of calling a method on a ref bean?

Tags: java, spring

Is it possible from Spring to inject the result of calling a method on a ref bean?

I'm trying to refactor some cut/pasted code from two separate projects into a common class. In one of the projects, the code lives in a class I'll call "MyClient" that is being instantiated from Spring. It is injected with another spring-instantiated class "MyRegistry", then the MyClient class uses that class to look up an endpoint. All I really need is the endpoint String in my refactored class, which can be initialized via a Setter. I really cannot have a dependency on MyRegistry from MyClient in the refactored code.

So, my question is this... is there a way I can inject the endpoint String from spring that was looked up in the MyRegistry class. So, I currently have:

```
<bean id="registryService" class="foo.MyRegistry">
...properties set etc...
</bean>

<bean id="MyClient" class="foo.MyClient">
    <property name="registry" ref="registryService"/>
</bean>
```

But I'd like to have (and I know this is imaginary Spring syntax)

```
<bean id="MyClient" class="foo.MyClient">
    <property name="endPoint" value="registryService.getEndPoint('bar')"/>
</bean>
```

where MyRegistry will have a method getEndPoint(Stirng endPointName)

Hope that makes sense from a the standpoint of what I'm trying to achieve. Please let me know if something like this is possible in Spring!

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The nicest solution is to use Spring 3's expression language as described by @ChssPly76, but if you're using an older version of Spring, it's almost as easy:

```
<bean id="MyClient" class="foo.MyClient">
   <property name="endPoint">
      <bean factory-bean="registryService" factory-method="getEndPoint">
         <constructor-arg value="bar"/>
      </bean>
   </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Very cool - and a little devious. We are using Spring 2.5.6 here so I will try to use this technique. I see what you're doing now... you treat the getEndPoint() method as a factory method on registryService - the "factory-constructed" class being a simple String representing the endPoint. Very cool! I hope this works!

Comment: "Devious" indeed, how dare you :)  This is exactly how `factory-bean` and `factory-method` are supposed to be used, I'll have you know :)

Answer (score 121):

It's possible in Spring 3.0 via [Spring Expression Language](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/spring-framework-reference/html/ch07s04.html):

```
<bean id="registryService" class="foo.MyRegistry">
...properties set etc...
</bean>

<bean id="MyClient" class="foo.MyClient">
  <property name="endPoint" value="#{registryService.getEndPoint('bar')}"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: @ChssPly76 Welcome, you are back

Comment: Damn, this comes in handy

Comment: Will this work if getEndPoint() logic has a dependency for the logic inside of it that hasn't been set at run time? For instance, maybe "endPoint" is a variable inside of `foo.MyRegistry` that doesn't have a value set yet, so at run time it is null and the `endPoint` in `MyClient` bean will be very confused when it is trying to be set?

Answer (score 3):

Or in Spring 2.x, by using a BeanPostProcessor

> Typically, bean post processors are used for checking the validity of bean properties **or altering bean properties** (what you want to) according to particular criteria.

```
public class MyClientBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor, ApplicationContextAware {

    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        return bean;
    }

    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        if((bean instanceof MyClient)) && (beanName.equals("MyClient"))) {
            Myregistry registryService = (Myregistry) applicationContext.getBean("registryService");

           ((MyClient) bean).setEndPoint(registryService.getEndPoint("bar"));
        }

        return bean;
    }
}
```

And register your BeanPostProcessor

```
<bean class="br.com.somthing.MyClientBeanPostProcessor"/>
```