# Injecting String property returned from some method in Java/Spring

Tags: java, spring

I have a class that looks like following.

```
Class Parser{
  private String fileName;
  Parser(String fileName){
    this.fileName = fileName;
  }
}
```

Now I want to instantiate this class using Spring but problem is that `fileName` here is not constant. It is of following format `FileToBeParsed_<ddMMyyyy>` where ddMMyyyy is current date time(whenever instantiation happens).

So I was thinking of writing a utility method to generate correct filename but how do I inject it in constructor?

Also is it a good practice to create beans of third party/library/JDK classes in your spring configuration.

Thanks

Comment: i think I found the answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520722/is-it-possible-from-spring-to-inject-the-result-of-calling-a-method-on-a-ref-bea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're using a version of spring that supports spring EL, then this should work for you:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean name="sdf" class="java.text.SimpleDateFormat">
        <constructor-arg value="yyyy/MM/dd" />
    </bean>

    <bean name="parser" class="sandbox.Parser">
        <constructor-arg value="#{sdf.format(new java.util.Date())}" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: I should also add that you need to make Parser constructor public

Answer (score 3):

You could inject filenamePrefix and append the date string in the constructor using a SimpleDateFormatter and some parsing of new Date()

```
Parser(String fileNamePrefix){
    String fileNameSuffix;
    //determine fileName suffix using new date and formatter
    ...

    this.fileName = fileNamePrefix + fileNameSuffix;
}
```

or if you dont like the idea of coding in a constructor you could make a FileNameGenerator class and inject that using constructor injection using the xml constructor-arg or Autowired annotation

```
@Autowired
Parser(FileNameGenerator fileNameGenerator){
    this.fileName = fileNameGenerator.getFileName();
}
```