# Is it possible to add dependency via `getText()` from TextField in Spring

Tags: java, spring, javafx

Is it possible to add a String dependency to an object, from a TextField input in `Spring`?

I'm thinking of a scenario where you'd want to persist a user's names into a database from user input got via TextField, or have a user's TextField input appear in a Label as the user types in.

For example, something else instead of:

```
<bean id="stringTextFieldInput" class="org.personClass">
    <property name="userName" value="Jon Doe" />
</bean>
```

In other words, how can I add a String dependency via `getText()` from TextField input, instead of using xml?

I'd like to have a user insert his\ her name via a textfield, `Jon Doe` in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is possible with the spring expression language:

```
<bean id="stringTextFieldInput" class="org.personClass">
  <property name="userName" value="#{myObject.getText()}" />
</bean>
```

Also have a look at this question: [Is it possible from Spring to inject the result of calling a method on a ref bean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520722/is-it-possible-from-spring-to-inject-the-result-of-calling-a-method-on-a-ref-bea?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks @markusw for your answer. So, for example, if I have a `TextField textField;` I'd do `value="#{textField.getText()}`? Would you please clarify if I'm wrong?

Comment: if `textField` is a Spring bean, yes.